# Best way to perform a reliability growth analysis and answering some questions like "the reliability is getting better?"

Tags: reliability, exploratory-data-analysis, reliability-meta-analysis

everyone!

I'm a reliability engineer and a project was given to me two weeks ago. I need to answer some questions about the reliability of a specific item in a train. There are 189 items, one for each equipment, and the failure data was given to me.
The item can be repaired and then reinstalled in another equipment.
The information I have is:

1. serial number - serial number for the specific item
2. start date - the date that each item started operating
3. failure date - the date that each item failed
4. repair date - the date that each item was repaired
5. failure mode - The failure mode that is related to the failure

So, I gather the information and treated the data based on the context that was given to me. Now I have the database ready to perform an analysis. But actually, I'm pretty lost on the analysis that I should perform to answer some questions like:

1. The reliability is getting better? (I have data from 2017 to 2023, approximately 300 points of data)
2. At which point the reliabilty started getting better?
3. The behavior for the first failure for each item differs too much from the behavior for the other failures? (Some items have more than 1 failure)
4. What's the overall MTBF for the fleet?

I'm trying to perform the analysis in Python, but I also have reliasoft Weibull++ available.
I don't know exactly when to use the time between failures as an input for the analysis or when to use the cumulative time of failure.
I already performed an exploratory analysis to understand a little bit more the data, and now I'm trying to do the [Laplace test](https://extapps.ksc.nasa.gov/Reliability/Documents/Laplace_Test.pdf) to verify if the trend is increasing or not.
I also tried to get the operational time for each month and then plot the time series to verify if there's any trend, but the problem is that in some months we don't have any failures, so the MTBF will not be available, like as shown in the image below. So this plot is not useful at all.

[image: MTBF Trend over time]

I just need some guidance on the kind of analysis I could perform to answer these questions precisely.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you explain what MTBF is?

Comment: The MTBF is the Mean Time Between Failures. It's a reliability metric, that basically divides the total time of operation by the number of failures in that period. 
Of course, it's not the most useful metric, as it only represents the result as a single point of data, but the MTBF is commonly used in  contracts to set the requirements. 
For exaxmple, the MTBF for a equipment every month could be 68,000 hours. So, if the calculated MTBF is below the requirement, the engineering team must build an action plan to improve the reliability.

Comment: Thanks - please edit that info into the question.